# looping json data in Class Component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is my **index.js** where I try to refer SampleApp

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import './index.css';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import SampleApp from "./pages/SampleApp";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      isUserAuthenticated: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => {
                    return (
                      <Redirect to="/SampleApp" />
                    )
                }}
              />
               <Route exact path="/SampleApp" component={SampleApp} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This is my **SampleApp.js** file. here I'm importing the **Cards** component from **Cards.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../src/App.css';
import Cards from '../cards/cards';

const SampleApp = props => (
  
  <React.Fragment>

    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div className="header">
          <div className="header_fonts">
            Sample Application
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="content_header_fonts">
            This is sample app
            </div>
          <div className="content_fonts">
            Sample app to deomntrate ideas.
          </div>
          <Cards></Cards>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>

  
)

export default SampleApp;
```

this is my **Cards.jsx** file.
here I'm importing **Card** component and json data

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from './cardUI';
import CardData from '../source/data.json';

class Cards extends Component {

    render() { 
        return 
        ( 
        <div className="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="row">
                {
                CardData.map((
                  {title, desc, icon, intro,developer_guide,api_ref }, id) => 
                  (
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                    <Card 
                    title={title} 
                    desc={desc} 
                    intro={intro} 
                    developer_guide={developer_guide} 
                    api_ref={api_ref}/>
                    </div>
                  ))
                  }

            
            </div>
        </div> 
        );
    }
}
 
export default Cards;
```

this is a sample of my JSON file

```
[
    {
        "id" : 7,
        "title" : "Melon Munchee",
        "icon" : "https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_393496.png",
        "desc" : "If you are an Avatar fan, then this api is for you. Here you can find everything from Episodes to Characters.",
        "intro": "intro_7",
        "developer_guide": "d_link7",
        "api_ref": "api_link7"
    },
    {
        "id" : 8,
        "title" : "Browns Barns",
        "icon" : "https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_386567.png",
        "desc" : "Baseball fans? Computer nerds? Now, in one place, you have baseball data and an api to access it. Have fun!.",
        "intro": "intro_8",
        "developer_guide": "d_link8",
        "api_ref": "api_link8"
    }
]
```

**Card.jsx** file
This is how implemented the Card component

```
import React from 'react';
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import * as Icon from '../../node_modules/react-bootstrap-icons';
import './card-style.css';


const Card = props =>{
    return(
     <div className="card text-center">
         <div className="card-body text-dark">
         <Icon.Alarm></Icon.Alarm>
            <h4 className="card-title">
                {props.title}
            </h4>
            <p className="card-text text-secondary">
                {props.desc}
            </p>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" className="card-link">{props.intro}</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" className="card-link">{props.developer_guide}</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" className="card-link">{props.api_ref}</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

but I'm getting an error as following

> Error: Cards(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually
> means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
> 19 stack frames were collapsed. Module.
> src/index.js:44   41 |   }   42 | }   43 |
>
> > 44 | render(, document.getElementById("root"));

Comment: Can we have a look at your data.json file?

Comment: Show the `Card` component. Also you mention "constructor" in your question, but there's no constructor in the shown component. Were you referring to the `Card` component?

Comment: let me include <Card/> and json file

Comment: Please include a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. I don't see any missing (explicit or implicit) return statements in the snippet.

Comment: Oh, check your `index.js` file, looks like you don't pass anything to render to `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: @DrewReese I just added the index.js file too, can you have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo mistake. When you use line terminator next to the `return` statement, JS adds semicolon automatically and that will be the end of function execution and returns `undefined`. That's why your `Cards` component is not able to find the JSX because Cards render returns `undefined`.

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion).

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.

To fix this, update Cards render function with this

```
 class Cards extends Component {
    render() { 
      return ( // was the issue earlier
      <div className="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div className="row">
              {
                CardData.map(({ title, desc, icon, intro,developer_guide,api_ref }, index) => (
                  <div className="col-md-4" key={title + index}>
                    <Card 
                    title={title} 
                    desc={desc} 
                    intro={intro} 
                    developer_guide={developer_guide} 
                    api_ref={api_ref} />
                  </div>
                  )
                )
              }
          </div>
      </div> 
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am actually going to take a guess here and say that your specific error is caused by the new line after your `return` statement. So remove it to make it look like this `return (` and it should work... or at least that error should go away.

Check out this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fog-y8pk2?file=/src/App.js
just go ahead and add a new line after the return and see your exact error.

Comment: I updated the question with more data, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to include your approach to mine :) let you know here